# Getting LinkedIn and Twitter to grab the appropriate content for previews

Tags: html, twitter, web-scraping, linkedin-api

How do you get LinkedIn and Twitter to fetch the appropriate content (image, title, description) from my web page when someone shares the link of that page with their networks / followers?

The title I gather comes from the  tag in html. The preview text from the meta 'description' tag, but what about the image preview or video preview if theirs a video embedded on the page?

Answer (score 0):

Found a useful resource here: https://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/46687/~/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin

The relevant tags are:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Title of the article"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://media.example.com/ 1234567.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Description that will show in the preview"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.example.com/URL of the article" />
```

And there's also Open Graph: http://ogp.me/